# Iris Detection or Red Eye Detection

Tags: computer-vision

I am trying to find a CV algorithm that detects Eyes, but my problem requires that the Eye Detection happens very accurate, I should maybe better call it Iris Detection. (not Recognition!). I was wondering if there is an efficient way and fast of doing this (real-time responsiveness). locates the Iris as it moves.

Any help, tutorials on online examples?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following article "A novel method for low-constrained iris boundary localization" from the ICB 2012. One of the steps is pupil and both limbic and pupillary boundary detection.

Kind regards,